Role Based Access Control With Auth0 and SpringBoot
I have a problem with assigning role-based access control on my SpringBoot application. I created a new API in Auth0 and assigned permissions to the API and enabled RBAC in the API. And authorized the API on the application. The application was assigned for SSO.
I have created the SecurityConfig.java as this
    public SecurityConfig(JwtAuthConverterConfig jwtAuthConverterConfig) {
        this.jwtAuthConverterConfig = jwtAuthConverterConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize

                        .requestMatchers("/", "/login", "/styles.css", "/templates/**", "/logout").permitAll()  // allow public access
                        .requestMatchers("/download-report").hasAuthority("SCOPE_download:report")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()  // other pages require authentication
                )
                .oauth2Login(oath2Login -> oath2Login
                        .loginPage("/login")  // custom login page
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/submit-form", true) // redirect after successful login
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")  // after logout, redirect to home page
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                )
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConverterConfig.customJwtAuthenticationConverter())
                        )
                );

        return http.build();
    }
}

Although I have kept the settings in Auth0, it will not authorize the user to connect to the  API. It gives a 403 error.
Could I need to form rules on implementing Role Based Access Control with Auth0?
Please help me to resolve this. Where I have got the error on the code. or on the Auth0 dashboard.

check your grant  reference link  https://frontegg.com/blog/oauth-grant-types

You must use the audience parameter to get a JWT access token from Auth0 that you can use to call from your regular web application built with Java Spring Boot.
Make sure to add your API audience as explained on the reference sample here.

Yeah, I have added my API identifier as the audience in my application. Formed permissions in the API and assigned them to the user. But it still gives me a 403 error on trying to access the endpoint.
Could you please tell me if I need to form rules on implementing Role Based Access Control with Auth0?

Are you getting the 403 error from Auth0 or your API server?

It's from my API server.  When I am calling the endpoint (/download-report) which is authorized with permission, it gives the 403 error.

Is there more detailed server error logs apart from the 403 error? I would also capture the issued access token and decode it using jwt.io to see if it has the expected permissions in the scope array.https://auth0.com/docs/troubleshoot/authentication-issues/troubleshoot-rbac-authorization
